# $A \subset B$ and $A \subseteq B$, what is the difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

So far I know that if $A \subset B$ then every element that is in $A$ will be also in $B$ but there will be at least one element in $B$ that is not in $A$

What about $A \subseteq B$? [This](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Set_Symbols.html) site says that $A \subseteq B$ says that "$A$ is a subset of $B$. set $A$ is included in set $B$." But well, it's pretty much the same definition as $A \subset B$.

So my question is, $A \subset B$ and $A \subseteq B$, what is the difference?

Comment: Sometimes people use $A\subset B$ to mean that $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ (i.e. all elements of $A$ are in $B$, but $B$ has some element(s) not in $A$). However, $A\subset B$ is usually used to mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$ (not necessarily proper). The notation $A\subseteq B$ means $A$ is a subset of $B$, and a better way to denote a proper subset is $A\subsetneq B$.

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ always means that $A=B$ is allowed. In some instances, $\subset$ is ambiguous - some authors use $A\subset B$ to exclude $A=B,$ others use it to mean the same as $\subseteq.$ (In that case, these authors will write $A\subsetneq B$ to ensure that $A\neq B.$

Answer (score 5):

It depends on convention. Some people use $A\subseteq B$ to mean $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $A=B.$ These people often use $A\subset B$ to denote proper subset. However, some use $A\subset B$ to mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $A=B.$ These people typically use $A\subsetneq B$ to denote a proper subset.

In general, $A\subseteq B$ allows for the case of $A=B,$ and $A\subsetneq B$ means that $A$ is a strict subset of $B$, while $A\subset B$ is the primary source of ambiguity.

Comment: +1 yeah, that's the right way to frame it.

Comment: I must be in another camp of mathematicians: I use $A\subseteq B$ to mean $A$ is a subset of $B$ (possibly being equal to $B$), while $A\subsetneq B$ means $A$ is a proper subset of $B$.

Comment: @Clayton That's probably the best way to do it, since it's the least ambiguous (in my opinion).

Comment: I mean, I guess it's just convention, but it seems like a terrible choice when every other order uses $<$ and $\leq$. I'm leaving my answer up in protest. :)

Comment: @MichaelBiro I typically use that notation myself (although I understand the confusion; it's just how I learned it)

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, these two symbols do mean exactly the same thing, unless the writer states otherwise. If you want to say that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$, you have to write $A\subsetneq B$.

Answer (score 0):

ETA: Apparently, I'm fighting against the tide of convention. Use whatever definition the author of your book uses.

$A \subseteq B$ is $A \subset B$ or $A = B$. It's analogous to $a < b$ vs $a \leq b$.

Comment: This is wrong. $A\subset B$ is usually taken to mean exactly the same as $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: @TonyK I disagree with the notion that they are "usually synonymous," but understand that they are occasionally. I've certainly seen authors use it as described in this post, and I would have judged it was more often the case.

Comment: Maybe some people use $A \subset B$ to mean $A \subseteq B$, but that seems like an abuse of the notation

Comment: @MichaelBiro In this, the "abuse" is usually due to an old standard. It is a more ancient view, I believe, due to (1) not really thinking of $\subset$ as a partial order, so not using that notion, and (2) typesetting was actual physical objects, so it was cheaper to have lots of $\subset$ and only a few $\subsetneq$ characters, and (3) $\subset$ in the "possibly equal" sense was a much more common usage.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough.